# AS3 - can't interact with swf file after loaded in

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I have this interactive swf file that I loaded externally as a background, everything's fine, but it's just not interactive anymore, I can't click on it. I googled this problem for a really long time and couldn't find an answer, I've tried the normal Flash way, and also using this library CASAlib, still couldnt find a solution. Does anyone know how to make this work? Thanks.

Cheers,
Christine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the objects on the foreground are preventing the background SWF from getting any mouse actions. It's hard to say anything without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

What is the ActionScript version of loader and loaded content? If it's 2 and 3 it will hapen as you say. If all is set to as3 it will work. Remeber about sandbox restrictions.